# replace null to empty string in Java

Tags: java, string

I have below string output :

```
["Kolkata","data can be, null",null,"05/31/2020",null]
```

but I want to have the output like below format in Java

```
["Kolkata","data can be, null","","05/31/2020",""]
```

please help me .

I am converting object to json data . Please see the below codes

```
List<String> test = new ArrayList<>();
List<Object[]> data =query.list();          
for (int i = 0; i < data.size(); i++) {
    Object[] row = (Object[]) data.get(i);

    String  jsonString = gson.toJson(row);
    test.add(jsonString);
}
```

I want to apply this on jsonString variable using java 7 as not using java 8

Comment: I don't see any java code here.  Please post a [mcve]

Comment: Does this data exist purely as a string or is it derived from a collection / array? If it's just a string, can you use a JSON library or something to parse it into a collection?

Comment: You should start by learning about loops.

Comment: What is the data structure? List? Array?

Answer (score 1):

If you have list for example list of like this

```
List<String> list = Arrays.asList("Kolkata","data can be, null",null,"05/31/2020",null);
    list.replaceAll(t -> Objects.isNull(t) ? "''" : t);
    System.out.println(list);
```

Here oputput will be:

```
[Kolkata, data can be, null, '', 05/31/2020, '']
```

Comment: Please do not assume that it is a list. Always clarify before posting answers. Although it works, please don't encourage such sloppy questions by answering them.

Comment: i am converting object to json data . Please see the below codes                 List<String> test = new ArrayList<>();
   List<Object[]> data =query.setParameterList("accIds", accIds).list();   
   for (int i = 0; i < data.size(); i++) {
    Object[] row = (Object[]) data.get(i);
    
    String jsonString = gson.toJson(row);
    //jsonString = jsonString.replace(null, "\"\"");
    test.add(jsonString);
   }                                                                                                             
     I want to apply this on jsonString variable